# How to turn the text into less known colors such as Burgundy?

Tags: color

It seems that the `\color` command just works with main colors. First, I want all my hyperlinks to be in a color a bit lighter than black. What is your suggestion? Second, how can I turn the text into less known colors?

Comment: Adding `\usepackage{xcolor}`,`\definecolor{Burgundy}{...}` und apply the new colour `Burgundy` in the  `\hypersetup`  command with `linkcolor` or in the call of `\usepackage[...]{hyperref}`

Comment: See the `xcolor` manual at `colors by name`, perhaps there is a colour which looks pretty much like your imagination of  `Burgundy` but has a different name there.  Please keep in mind how readable your link will be after using such colours

Comment: `texdoc xcolor` as @ChristianHupfer says. `\usepackage[x11names,dvipsnames,svgnames]{xcolor}` for the full range of pre-defined colours.

Comment: Also `\colorlet{Burgandy}{red!65!black}` is another way to go.

Comment: What is your current setup that yields your hyperlinks to be black? Let's first start on the same page before shooting our random possible solutions...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here are some `Burgundy` colours as defined by Wikipedia or other sites (left column of the table) and some colours as defined in the documentation of `xcolor` close to Burgundy:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[x11names, svgnames, dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\definecolor{Burgundy}{RGB}{144,0,32}
\definecolor{Burgundy1}{RGB}{128,0,32}
\definecolor{Burgundy2}{RGB}{158,5,8}
\definecolor{VividBurgundy}{RGB}{159,29,53}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{rl@{\hspace{4em}}rl}
  \color{Burgundy}Burgundy (Wikipedia) & \color{Burgundy}\rule{2cm}{1.25cm} & \color{DarkRed}DarkRed (SVGnames) & \color{DarkRed}\rule{2cm}{1.25cm} \\
  \addlinespace
  \color{VividBurgundy}Vivid Burgundy (Wikipedia) & \color{VividBurgundy}\rule{2cm}{1.25cm} & \color{FireBrick}FireBrick (SVGnames) & \color{FireBrick}\rule{2cm}{1.25cm} \\
  \addlinespace
  \color{Burgundy1}Burgundy1 & \color{Burgundy1}\rule{2cm}{1.25cm} & \color{Maroon}Maroon (dvipsnames) & \color{Maroon}\rule{2cm}{1.25cm} \\
  \addlinespace
  \color{Burgundy2}Burgundy2 & \color{Burgundy2}\rule{2cm}{1.25cm} & \color{Maroon}Maroon (dvipsnames) & \color{BrickRed}\rule{2cm}{1.25cm}
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]